# How I detect SimpleDateFormat file/files name is on download folder android 11?

Tags: java, android

Hello i use this SimpleDateFormat to save .mp3 files on Download folder, i want a method how I check if a file / files with this style format is on Download folders or not?

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss_ddMMyyyy", Locale.US);
    Date now = new Date();
                AudioSavaPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +""+ formatter.format(now) + ".mp3";
```

so on download folder created files like this :
154637_22022022.mp3,161201_23022022.mp3,171131_23022022.mp3...

how I detect if files with this format is on download folder because every time name change on download folder based on current date and time...

Comment: It is unclear what exactly your problem to do that would be. So please describe some steps you could do. Tell what the big problem is here.

Comment: String name1 = "121212_02022022.mp3"; String name2 = "mysong.121212_02022022.mp3" String name3="anicesong.mp3";  You have code to determine if these names are valid?

Comment: @blackapps friend I edit my first post, now is more clear the problem please check, also we need code only to detect files with this date format HHmmss_ddMMyyyy.mp3 NOT all *.mp3....

Comment: No. You did not give any extra info. We knew that all as you can see on my second comment. Please reread my first comment and then elaborate. Tell what difficulty you have.

Comment: To make it yourself easy create a subfolder in Download folder. Only put such files in it. Then you know that all files are valid.

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions. They should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) to check if the filename is in the format you want, using regex.

example

```
fileName.matches(".*[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{8}.*")
```

Regex meaning:

- `.*` match any character arbitrary number of times
- `[0-9]{6}` match a number 6 times
- `_` match underscore
- `[0-9]{8}` match a number 8 times
- `.*` match any character arbitrary number of times

You can tweak the regex if it doesn't fit your case.